# File write is not successful after 950ko

Tags: c#

i just got back to c# to create a csv to sql translator for one of my project.
However i came accross a weird behaviour and my google search was not successful, so i need your help.

Here is the following code ( tiddied for the occasion, and don't my the poor quality, i'm no csharp expert)

```
string line, generated;
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("data.sql", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
System.IO.StreamWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("source.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] ar = line.Split('|');
            generated = "INSERT INTO `translation` VALUES('" + ar[0] + "'," + ar[1] + ");";
            w.WriteLine(generated);
        }
// Closing file stuff
```

The file is successfully created and greatly generated for small files. However when i use it on large file the resulting file is truncated (always at the same place and with a resulting file of 950ko~)

The result is like this

```
INSERT INTO `translation` VALUES ( 'trans1', 1 );
INSERT INTO `translation` VALUES ( 'trans2', 2 );
INSERT INTO `translation` VALUES ( 'trans3', 3 );
INSERT INTO `tran
```

I miss 6 lines.
So if anyone got an idea i'll gladely listen to eagerly

PS: I could easily solve this by chunking my source file, however I'm really curious about this issue and can't think it is a .Net issue, i must have done something wrong.

Regards all

The closing stuff

```
w.Close();
file.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Edit: solution
Following people recommendation the solution to my problem was the following

```
// Replacing my FileStream and StreamWriter by the following line
System.IO.StreamWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter("data.sql", false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
// Removing the fs.Close()
```

It now work like a charm. I could be cleaner by using the 'using' keyword to avoid calling the Close function ( like Mehrdad said ) but i don't like to add an extra set of { } ( my taste )

Thank you all

Comment: Can you show how you "close the file stuff?"

Comment: I think you might be forgetting to call [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Seems like you are not calling Flush...

Comment: The flush done the trick. Forgot my csharp basics how lame

Comment: You'll get this behavior when you call fs.Close() first, preventing the StreamWriter from flushing itself.  I have to guess that your last snippet isn't accurate.  You should not use a FileStream at all, just the StreamWriter is enough

Comment: The documentation does say that `Close` will also flush.

Comment: You should not need `Flush` if you do it in order, as `Close` will `Flush`. Regardless, you should not be using `FileStream`, as Hans pointed out, and you should be using `using (StreamWriter sw = ...) {` instead of closing explicitly.

Comment: @grifos Re your update: it's not just a matter of taste. It's a matter of exception-safety. If something throws an exception in the middle of the process, before `Close` is called explicitly, you'll end up with an open file handle.

Comment: Can you please put your edit as an answer so people know this problem has been solved and dont waste time reading it. Thanks.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari: +1 for the using. Using is your best friend. without the using, you have to create a messy nested try/catch/finally block, where you have to test the state of the object to close. WIth using, the compiler is doing everything for you, and the code is far more easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my question is:

```
string line, generated;
using(System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("source.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)){
   using(System.IO.StreamWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter("data.sql", false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)){
     while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
        String[] ar = line.Split('|');
        generated = "INSERT INTO `translation` VALUES('" + ar[0] + "'," + ar[1] + ");";
        w.WriteLine(generated);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code suppose you trust the `source.txt` file. It's an easy way to inject SQL script to your DB. Ensure the correctness of this file, and add some checks related to the format of ar[] vlaues

Comment: I'm providing the 'source.txt' file, so SQLi is not and issue =). But i agree if the source.txt was generated from an outside resource, i would have test the read value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're closing both `w` and `fs`, in that order (i.e. in the opposite order to which they were opened)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `Flush` the `StreamWriter` before "file closing stuff".